# How to balance studies and part time job

Tags: undergraduate, job

I am an undergraduate student of software engineering, second year now, in a foreign country. My family's economic background isn't very strong; so I need to work in a restaurant for part time job in order to balance my personal finance. Recently, I got so much involved in my job that I stopped paying much attention to my classes. And since the language problem in this foreign country is a black spot for me, the classes are too difficult for me to be handled. Now, I am about to fail two main courses in this semester. Should I just cut off my job load and take these subjects next semester again or just give up with this place and look for some other place, where the communicating problems don't exist?

Comment: "Working part time in a restaurant" and "got so much involved in my job" do not make sense. How a 4-hour job (that probably is on weekends or nights) interferes with your morning studies?

Comment: it's not just a 4 hour job, i work as a host so i need to stay for a longer amount of time. And about classes, I actually don't understand anything because of the language problem. Thus I need to do my own research for everything. So me being too much involved in my part time job, i couldn't make time to do those research so I am in a verge of failing the course. I think I really need counseling.

Answer (score 3):

You should take two cases into account, simultaneously:

- Concentration on the courses, deservedly.
- Keeping on earning some money.

***You might be lucky enough to be recruited for an academic-driven working position in the university, as either TA or RA, instead of working out of the university.***

Such approach (as a potential solution) could lead to some accomplishments for you:

1. Your work is in the academic atmosphere... It not only lets you keep
   yourself in the mood of university, but will be considerably helpful
   to improve your academic linguistic skills, as the right thing you
   need, now...
2. Your current working site might be far from the university. Transporting
   back and forth does waste both your time and energy (and even your money!). Involving in a job within the university lets you share your energy, in every aspect, within all of
   your plans, in a more optimized way.
3. Your salary could be even more by working in the university, if you
   could prove your both enthusiasm and capability to handle the tasks.
4. Such academic activities in the university (putting aside the
   acquired financial outcomes) will strengthen your progression within
   the path of studying and potential research; because, as an
   instance, you can find your research path, under the aegis of a RA
   position. A TA position would also lead to deepening all of the subjects,
   were which unresolved for yourself, partially, in a complete manner.
5. ...

It does not sound to be a bad idea, does it?!..

Best

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [Matinking's answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/61017/10220).

Regardless of whether you can get an academic-driven job on campus, consider teaming up with another student taking the same courses.

Your ideal foil would be fully fluent in the language of instruction, but weaker than you on independent research. The idea would be to work together on understanding the material, and also work as a team for group projects. Interacting with your study-partner might help improve your fluency in the language of instruction.